# Return View in Laravel not displaying proper URL

Tags: php, url, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I'm into routing now via use of resource routing

here is my code in router,

```
Route::resource('item-sales', 'ItemSalesController');
```

Here is my code in my controller

```
return View::make('item-sales.create')
```

When I return the view it does not make the URL I need it shows,

```
URL - item-sales/
```

What I need/Expected output of URL is,

```
URL - item-sales/create
```

Here's my controller

```
 public function store()
        {
               $id = Input::get('item_id');
                $new_item = Item::find($id);
                $new_qty = Input::get('item_quantity');
                $total = $new_item->item_price * $new_qty;
                Session::put('added-items', [
                    0 => [
                        'item_id'       => $id,
                        'item_name'     => $new_item->item_name,
                        'item_price'    => $new_item->item_price,
                        'item_category'    => $new_item->category,
                        'item_quantity' => Input::get('item_quantity')
                    ]
                ]);
                $array = Session::get('added-items');
                $total = number_format($total, 2, '.', ',');
                return View::make('item-sales.create')
                ->with('items',$array)
                ->with('total',$total);
    }
```

Comment: route correspond to the method used in the controller and not the rendered view. You are working in which method/action ?

Comment: What do you mean ? what would I need is to fix URL to display it as item-sales/create not item-sales, its action is from controller @webNeat

Comment: I mean if your code `return View::make('item-sales.create')` is written in the `index` method of your controller. The URL will be `/item-sales`. check this http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: yes it is in index how can I able to use /item-sales/create ?

Comment: Please add the code of your controller to your question so that we can help you

Comment: Controller Added @webNeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need your own custom methods and individual routes with a single route, then use the restful routing.

In Routes.php:

```
Route::controller('item-sales', 'ItemSalesController');
```

In ItemSalesController.php:

```
public function getCreate() {
   $id = Input::get('item_id');
   $new_item = Item::find($id);
   $new_qty = Input::get('item_quantity');
   $total = $new_item->item_price * $new_qty;
   Session::put('added-items', [
             0 => [
                    'item_id'       => $id,
                    'item_name'     => $new_item->item_name,
                    'item_price'    => $new_item->item_price,
                    'item_category'    => $new_item->category,
                    'item_quantity' => Input::get('item_quantity')
                  ]
   ]);
   $array = Session::get('added-items');
   $total = number_format($total, 2, '.', ',');

   return View::make('item-sales.create')
              ->with('items',$array)
              ->with('total',$total);
}
```

Then in Url: route to: item-sales/create

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Resource Controller](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) in documentation. It's action is mapped to methods using `HTTP` verbs. So, for example, To show a form for creating a resource the method should be `create` and request method should be `GET` and `URL` should be `/item-sales/create`.

```
Verb         Path                         Action    Route Name

GET          /resource                    index     resource.index

// Follow this one

GET          /item-sales/create           create    item-sales.create

POST         /resource                    store     resource.store
GET          /resource/{resource}         show      resource.show
GET          /resource/{resource}/edit    edit      resource.edit
PUT/PATCH    /resource/{resource}         update    resource.update
DELETE       /resource/{resource}         destroy   resource.destroy
```

To make sure about routes and route name's run `php artisan routes` from your command prompt (terminal) and use the route names and urls exactly.

The `store` method is for saving and used `POST` method/http verb and the `URL` would be `/item-sales`. To show a form for creating new resource (By taking user inputs in the form) you should use `create` method and in this case the `http` verb would be `GET`. So your action should be like this:

```
public function create()
{
    // Return the view (empty form)
    // app/views/item-sales/create.blade.php
    return Vire::make('item-sales.create');
}
```

To access/invoke this method you should use `item-sales/create` as `URL`. Then when you submit the form for saving, use the `store` method, so, form's action could be something like `route('item-sales.store')`.

Comment: Should I declare another route to custom it as item-sales/create ?

Comment: No, you should use `Laravel`'s `artisan` command to create your resource controller, `php artisan controller:make YourController` and `Laravel` will create all the methods for you.

Comment: I already do that, I have this controller with boiler I needed, but when I tried to return make a view it does fine but the URL seems wrong.

Comment: What is the method/action you used to show the form ?

Comment: its, `return View::make('item-sales.create')` @WereWolf

Comment: What is the method name, is that `public function create() { ... }` ?

Comment: Controller Added @WereWolf